# XSLT Get Total Count while in the for loop

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm in my for loop

```
<xsl:for-each select="Alerts/AlertItem">
```

and

```
<xsl:value-of select="position()" />
```

gets me the current position, the index. So each time it would give me 1,2 and 3 assuming there are 3 items.

While inside this for loop, how do i get the total count of 3? And not the index?

Before the for loop i can get it with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(descendant::AlertItem[Code='2'])" />
```

but inside the loop i have tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(parent::AlertItem[Code='2'])" />
<xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::AlertItem[Code='2'])" />
<xsl:value-of select="count(AlertItem[Code='2'])" />
```

All return 0

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: Working on it, gimme some time. It's a long xslt to sanitize :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count preceding sibling (or preceding) nodes. Not sure why you need this, it's not very efficient.

Note also that the `last()` function will return the total count of the currently processed node set (overall, not depending on the position of the currently processed node).

Comment: I have a list of items that go into categories, based on codes above. My document has to be xhtml 1.0 strict compliant. When there are 0 elements in the category. The `table` doesn't close properly, so i need to add a closing statement if the count is 0

Comment: Thank you, both yours and C. M. Sperberg Mc Queen's solution work. I went a different route though because i wanted to maintain my current efficiency and didn't want to add unnecessary choose statements. I always an one empty row to the table, it has a height of 0, so it's always there but not visible. This makes me XHTML 1.0 Strict compliant :)

Answer (score 0):

Before the `for-each` instruction, define a variable with the desired information:

```
<xsl:variable name="total-count" select="count(Alerts/AlertItem)"/>
<xsl:for-each select="Alerts/Alertitem">
  <xsl:message>Now processing item <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    of <xsl:value-of select="$total-count"/>
   ...       
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Both solutions work but i found something even simpler that worked for me and maintained the efficiency. I always append an empty row with height 0 to the end to make sure it's strict compliant.